# Connecting SQL Statements by If statement in PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

The third query doesn't work but the first two query in the if statement doesn't have any problem. I'm trying to create an advanced search in PHP with date and filters. Is there a limit in using "AND" in sql?

Any tips to help me get a better sql statement than this?

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `work` WHERE `remarks` = 'PENDING' AND `College` IN($college12)";



if (!empty($search) && !empty($criteria)) {
  $sql2 .= "AND `$criteria` LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $start,$limit";
}

if (!empty($dateFrom) && !empty($dateTo)) {
  $sql2 .= "AND Date_App >= '$dateFrom' AND Date_App <= '$dateTo' LIMIT $start,$limit";
}

if (!empty($dateFrom) && !empty($dateTo) && !empty($search) && !empty($criteria)) {
  $sql2 .= "AND Date_App >= '$dateFrom' AND Date_App <= '$dateTo' AND `$criteria` LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $start,$limit";
}
```

Comment: There's no limit, but make sure you're using `else if` instead of just `if`. Right now, you could possibly hit multiple ifs. If that happens, you'd have multiple LIMITs with some in the wrong spots.

Comment: Though you could eliminate the last `if`, and move the LIMIT query out of the IF checks and just append it after. And make sure you add some spacing at the beginning/end of your variables or else you're going to have issues.

Comment: Yes, if all 4 are !empty then your query is this `SELECT * FROM work WHERE remarks = 'PENDING' AND College IN($college12)AND $criteria LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $start,$limitAND Date_App >= '$dateFrom' AND Date_App <= '$dateTo' LIMIT $start,$limitAND Date_App >= '$dateFrom'AND Date_App <= '$dateTo' AND $criteria LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $start,$limit`